# WPF Global Class MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In trying to setup a global class in `App.xaml`;

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:MySettingsClass x:Key="GlobalSettings" />
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <!-- My Resources -->
    </ResourceDictionary >
</Application.Resources>
```

Although I am getting an error message of

> Each dictionary entry must have an associated key.

and

> 'App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now I can go in and and an `x:Key` to `ResourceDictionary` but I have never seen anyone do that, so that seems wrong.  The second error message leads me to believe that I am doing this wrong.

Do I have the wrong solution for this problem or is something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.Resources IS a resource dictionary, implicitly. You could just slap resources right in there. This would be valid:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:MySettingsClass x:Key="GlobalSettings" />
    <!-- Pretty much anything with an x:Key attribute. -->
</Application.Resources>
```

But if you're merging dictionaries you do need the explicit `<ResourceDictionary>` tag, and usually in App.xaml you're merging dictionaries.

The problem you ran into is that in your XAML, the first thing it sees is your `GlobalSettings` resource, before anything. That's the first thing it sees, so it figures OK, he's just slapping some resources in here. It creates a `ResourceDictionary` and proceeds to add everything it sees to that. Next thing it sees is `<ResourceDictionary>`, and it thinks you're trying to add another resource dictionary to the first one as a resource, but without an `x:Key` attribute. I tried just now and it did let me add one with `x:Key`, not that I know of any reason to do that. It didn't merge the resources into the outer one.

Try this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!-- One of My Resources -->
        <local:MySettingsClass x:Key="GlobalSettings" />

        <!-- My Other Resources -->

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Merged dictionaries -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you keep getting the InitializeComponent error, please share your code for App.xaml.cs

Comment: Thanks figured it was something simple.  I moved it into the ResourceDictionary and got an error.  Originally thought it was the same error, turns out it was something different.